# How do I set an ASP.NET Label text from code behind on page load?

Tags: asp.net, label

I can't seem to find an answer out there for this. Here's the scenario:
I have an ASP.NET project using C#. I'm loading data (Username, email, etc...) from a sqlite database with C# (using ADO). I'll be loading the data into static Global variables in a class file in my App_Data folder. I need to be able to insert the username into an ASP.NET Label on a page during load.

In PHP, I would just do it like this:

```
<?php
function GetUserName() {
//code which retrieves username from db.
return username;
}
?>
<p>Here is the username: <?php echo GetUserName(); ?></p>
```

Can anyone explain how this is done? I'm new to ASP.NET.

Here's an update for some more detail. I tried what you guys have suggested. My page load function is in a file called RankPage.aspx.cs and the table below it is in RankPage.aspx. The idea is to list a bunch of users that I've retrieved from the database. I threw in 'myLabel' just to test it. Right now, without declaring 'myLabel' in my code behind, it errors that 'myLabel' does not exist in the current context. If I declare 'myLabel' using the FindControl() function, I get a runtime exception that 'myLabel' isn't set to an instance of an object.

Here's the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Label myLabel = this.FindControl("myLabel") as Label;
        myLabel.Text = "my text";
    }
}

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Current User -->
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label id="currentUserName" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label id="currentUserScore" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- End Current User -->

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For this label:

```
<asp:label id="myLabel" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind use (C#):

```
myLabel.Text = "my text";
```

---

Update (following updated question):

You do not need to use `FindControl` - that whole line is superfluous:

```
  Label myLabel = this.FindControl("myLabel") as Label;
  myLabel.Text = "my text";
```

Should be just:

```
  myLabel.Text = "my text";
```

The Visual Studio designer should create a file with all the server side controls already added properly to the class (in a `RankPage.aspx.designer.cs` file, by default).

You are talking about a `RankPage.cs` file - the way Visual Studio would have named it is `RankPage.aspx.cs`. How are you linking these files together?

Comment: hmm... That's what I tried initially, but it didn't work. Maybe I'm running into a different problem? I'm getting an error that the label doesn't exist in the current context. I'm putting the code in the Page_Load of the aspx.cs file...

Comment: @David - that _should_ work. It would be better to see your actual aspx markup for the label and the code in the `page_load` handler instead of your PHP code.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what happened. I'm developing in MonoDevelop, but the project was originally created in Visual Studio. Somehow the RankPage.aspx.designer.cs was deleted when I converted the project. And RankPage.cs was a typo, I meant RankPage.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are just placing the code on the page, usually the code behind will get an auto generated field you to use like @Oded has shown.

In other cases, you can always use this code:

```
Label myLabel = this.FindControl("myLabel") as Label; // this is your Page class

if(myLabel != null)
   myLabel.Text = "SomeText";
```

Comment: Using 'Label myLabel = this.FindControl("myLabel") as Label;' throws an object reference not set to an instance of an object error, as though it couldn't find the element on the page. And I know that element is on the page...

Comment: Well, the best choice is to do null checking; if the control is not a Label, the "as Label" part of the statement will mean it will return null. I'll alter the example to be more safe.

Answer (score 2):

In your ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" />
```

In your code behind (assuming you're using C#):

```
function Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       UserNameLabel.Text = "User Name";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a long while ago, and it has been marked answered, but to me, the selected answer was not answering the question I thought the user was posing.  It seemed to me he was looking for the approach one can take in ASP .Net that corresponds to his inline data binding previously performed in php.

Here was his php:

```
<p>Here is the username: <?php echo GetUserName(); ?></p>
```

Here is what one would do in ASP .Net:

```
<p>Here is the username: <%= GetUserName() %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the page load event you set your label

`lbl_username.text = "some text";`

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myLabel.Text = "My text";
}
```

this is the base of ASP.Net, thinking in controls, not html flow.

Consider following a course, or reading a beginner book... and first, forget what you did in php :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your aspx page

```
<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

and then in your codebehind you can just do

```
myLabel.Text = "My Label";
```