# How do I fill in text on an ASP.NET page from a C# program?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to fill in an ASP.NET page textbox with some predefined text so that when it is displayed the value is predefined. I have tried

```
protected void Page_PreRender ()
{
    mytextbox.Text = somestring;
}
```

which works fine in the development environment but on the server produces...

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

The same applies when I try this in `Page_Load`. As I read the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331968/how-do-i-set-an-asp-net-label-text-from-code-behind-on-page-load) question, what I am trying should work (in at least one of these places).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT** more code, as suggested. The C# looks like this:-

```
    protected void Page_PreRender (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string [] file_list;
            int i = 0;

            file_list = Directory.GetFiles(MyProg.Common.GetDirectory(),
                                           MyProg.Common.GetFileNameRoot() + "*.*");

            foreach (string filename in file_list)
            {
                string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName (filename);

                if (filenameonly == MyProg.Common.GetFileNameRoot() + "runlog.log")
                {
                    nametextbox.Text = filenameonly;
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string mystring = ex.ToString();
            errorMessage.Text = "Page Load Error : " + mystring;
        }

    }
```

and the ASP.NET page like this...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"
         AutoEventWireup="true"
         CodeBehind="MyDialogue.aspx.cs"
         Inherits="MyDialogue" %>
<%@ Register assembly="ComponentArt.Web.UI"
             namespace="ComponentArt.Web.UI"
             tagprefix="ComponentArt" %>
<%@ Register assembly="ComponentArt.Web.Visualization.Charting"
             namespace="ComponentArt.Web.Visualization.Charting"
             tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
<div style="visibility:hidden">
<asp:TextBox ID="nametextbox"
             TextMode="MultiLine"
             runat="server"
             Visible="true" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: NullReferenceException in this code means one of 2 things: Either `somestring` is null or `mytextbox` is null. You need to figure out which.

Comment: How do you deploy to production server?

Comment: Did you publish in production servers the right version of the aspx file? It seems that aspx file does not contain a textbox with that name.

Comment: Something in the auto-generated code went awry.. try adding this line to your class on top of the functions: `protected TextBox mytextbox;` hopefully it will be enough.

Comment: @Brian Hooper: No one can really help you unless you post some meaningful code (both html and code behind) that matches exactly (or at least very closely) what you're putting onto the production server.

Comment: @Joel, I have supplied more code; apologies for not doing so before (I was trying to keep it short...)

Comment: I wonder what happens if no files match for your loop :)  Do you want a page load error?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, the definition appears in the aspx.designer.cs file. That'd be sufficient, wouldn't it?

Comment: So maybe as others said, the DLL file wasn't copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be several areas that are causing this problem. How are you sure that you've narrowed it down to the textbox itself? Was this code completely bug-free before adding the textbox message? I'll post your code below with where I think potential null references may be occurring (in comments):

```
string [] file_list;
int i = 0;

file_list = Directory.GetFiles(MyProg.Common.GetDirectory(),
                               MyProg.Common.GetFileNameRoot() + "*.*");

// it is possible that file_list is null
// potentially due to an invalid path (missing / perhaps?)
foreach (string filename in file_list)
{
    string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName (filename);

    // It's possible that the MixedZone.Kernel.Common library
    // is experiencing the null reference exception because it
    // may not understand what file to get the name root of or 
    // maybe it is not capable of getting the root for some
    // other reason (permissions perhaps?)
    if (filenameonly == MixedZone.Kernel.Common.GetFileNameRoot() + "runlog.log")
    {
        nametextbox.Text = filenameonly;
    }
```

Some possible solutions or safer code:

```
string [] file_list;
int i = 0;

file_list = Directory.GetFiles(MyProg.Common.GetDirectory(),
                               MyProg.Common.GetFileNameRoot() + "*.*");

if (file_list == null) throw new Exception("File List is null. Something is wrong.");

foreach (string filename in file_list)
{
    string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName (filename);

    string fileroot = MixedZone.Kernel.Common.GetFileNameRoot();
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileroot) throw new Exception("MixedZone Library failed.");

    if (filenameonly.Equals(fileroot + "runlog.log", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) // Choose your own string comparison here
    {
        nametextbox.Text = filenameonly;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, Joel. I'll try the things you suggest. I was using 'works on my machine' as a surrogate indicator for 'bug free', which may not be quite correct.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Joel. The `Directory.GetFiles` was indeed failing, although how it kept running long enough to throw an exception where it did is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

This should work without complaint. Does the `mytextbox` control have the `runat="server"` attribute? You can only access from the codebehind stuff with the runat="server" attribute.

Comment: mmm, not sure Oliver, PreRender is the last moment when he can set that value and should work not worse than PageLoad for what he needs to do.

Comment: Ouch, my mistake. I may have been thinking of a different event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the text box does have the `runat="server"` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Did you publish your site but did the filerefence to the codebehind stay in the aspx page? 
are you sure the dll in the bin folder?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The Publish feature is not working for some reason; I shipped the application over to the server by rebuilding and then copying over all the files that changed (Tortoise helps with this).

Comment: Ok, your welcome.. but it didn't fix your problem though.. are you working with a Masterpage? if so, did you take [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx) into account? you'll need to ref the contentplaceholder first..

Comment: Er...I haven't the least idea. How would I tell?

Comment: i just saw your code, as suggested below the null ref could come from many places.. i thought it was just a simple ref to a textbox. GL with fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Run with Antivirus disabled on the Production Server?

Compare .Net versions between Production and Development?

Answer (score 1):

"which works fine in the development environment but on the server produces" - so, permissions or missing files perhaps?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion; I can see the files on the server using ftp (permissions may be a bit more problematic, though).