# 'Writing' HTML Code in C# SharePoint Web Part

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint

I'm trying to figure out a way where I can write html code to a SharePoint Web Part with C#. I don't even know if this is possible but I'm assuming it is. In JavaScript it would just be something along the lines of `document.write("<br>" + variable + "</b>")` so I'm just trying to figure out how this will work in C#. There is a much bigger picture than this but this is the basic portion I'm stuck on.

I would like the HTML Code to be inside of the `for` loop below.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using System.Web;

namespace CSharpAttempt.VisualWebPart1
{

public class getTheSPItems
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            string theHtmlString = "<b>" + i + "</b>";
            Response.Write(theHtmlString);

        }
    }
}



public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SharePoint WebPart is just an ASP.NET control.

You can add any other SharePoint controls, WebControls, or html to it by adding to the controls collection.

```
this.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("div") { InnerText ="My HTML"});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a better example, please?

Comment: in your VisualWebPart1UserControl class, in the Page_Load() method, you   would add the snippet above. I am not sure what your getTheSPItems class is for - that wouldn't be called at all based on your code above.

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'HtmlGenericControl' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CSharpAttempt\CSharpAttempt\VisualWebPart1\VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs 32 35 CSharpAttempt

Comment: add using `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;` to your cs file.

Comment: Perfect. Would there be an easier way to write a block of HTML code rather than defining a tag, saying that goes into it and so fourth?

Comment: `this.Response.Write("<div>my html</div>")`

Comment: Whenever I Use `this.Response.Write("<div>my html</div>")` my text ends up outside of the web (on top of the web page). Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use it - it renders directly to the response stream, which is not what you are trying to accomplish. Use the method in the snippet above -it's about as generic as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer,

```
Response.Write (theHtmlString);
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)


Or

If you want to add it to a specific part of your page then drag on a literal control to your webform.

Use

```
LiteralControlName.Text = theHtmlString;
```

Comment: Yea I cannot figure this Response.Write out. Everytime I try and use it I get an error: **The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: @mwilson add system.web, I only see system.web.ui

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you put an ASP.Net control on the page and give it an ID you can refer to it in code behind very trivially.

See this stack overflow answer: [How do I set an ASP.NET Label text from code behind on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331968/how-do-i-set-an-asp-net-label-text-from-code-behind-on-page-load)

**EDIT:** see this new SO answer for basic ASP.Net form manipulation