# Calling Static method on aspx page does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page named MasterPage_MyMasterPage on whic i have created a static method as

```
public static string GetRoleName()
    {
        string sRoleName="admin";


        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] != null)
        {
            sRoleName = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
        }
        return sRoleName;
    }
```

and on aspx page i called it as

```
<a >Brayan <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%= MasterPage_MyMasterPage.GetRoleName() %>' ></asp:Label>
```

but it doesn't worked, it print as ...

```
Brayan <span><%= MasterPage_MyMasterPage.GetRoleName() ;></span>
```

Session["UserName"] is bind when login successfull.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey please try this works for me

```
<a >Brayan <asp:Label runat="server" Text='' ><%= MasterPage_MyMasterPage.GetRoleName()%>     </asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Inline expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.100).aspx) using the `<%= ... %>` syntax can be used to render to the page.

But they can't be used to set a server-control property, which is what you're attempting to do (Label.Text property).

Consider using [data-binding syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bda9bbfx(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

```
... Text = "<%# MasterPage_MyMasterPage.GetRoleName() %>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= ((MasterPage_MyMasterPage)Page.Master).GetRoleName() %>
```

Update:

Make a protected method in your cs file something like this

```
protected string getRoleName()
{
    return ((MasterPage_MyMasterPage)Page.Master).GetRoleName();
}
```

and in aspx file

```
<%= getRoleName() %>
```

Comment: error occured :Error 114 Member 'MasterPage_MyMasterPage.GetRoleName()' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the same as this one?

[How do I set an ASP.NET Label text from code behind on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331968/how-do-i-set-an-asp-net-label-text-from-code-behind-on-page-load)