# On Page_Load, replace HTML text with generated text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So my HTML looks a little bit like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>@@Street@@</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@@CityStateZip@@<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    </td>
</tr>
```

So on my C# page, on Page_Load, I want to replace `@@Street@@` and `@@CityStateZip@@` with the actual value. For example, I want to do something like this.

```
string.Replace("@@Street@@","123 Sample Street");
```

and then when the page fully loads, it will show 123 Sample Street instead of `@@Street@@`

Is there any way to do this? If not, how would I accomplish this alternatively?

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label id="streetLabel" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><asp:Label id="cityZipLabel" runat="server" /><br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    </td>
</tr>
```

in your page load:

```
Page_load()
{
if(!isPostBack)
{
   streetLabel.Text= "Replace your text here";
}
}
```

Comment: Off topic question, but why do I need the if statement to check if it's a PostBack? The code seems to work fine without it.

Comment: you can use it when you need to execute something ONLY on first load.  Classic usage of 'IsPostBack' is data binding / control initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Use `labels`

eg:

For this label:

```
<asp:label id="lblStreet" runat="server" />
```

In the code behind use (C#):

```
lblStreet.Text = "Sample Street";
```

[How do I set an ASP.NET Label text from code behind on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331968/how-do-i-set-an-asp-net-label-text-from-code-behind-on-page-load)

Comment: Okay so in this case, I should just replace all of my code with <asp:Labels> ??

Comment: Yup, thatd be the asp.net way of doing things.

Comment: In that case, would it let me edit <table>s or do I have to create an <asp:Table>