# c# - Web form constructor error

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor, webforms

I'm a beginner at C# and am trying to build a simple constructor that outputs variables to a label.

When I run the code below, I get the error message "The name 'Label1' does not exist in the current context".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace handin1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string Password;

    public Person()
    {
        Name = "John Doe";
        Age = 30;
        Password = "password";
    }
}

public class PersonBuilder
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person t = new Person();
        Label1.Text = t.Password;
    }
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well `PersonBuilder` doesn't have a `Label1` field or property - what do you expect it to refer to? (Additionally, you don't normally have a `Main` method like this in an ASP.NET app... how do you expect that to be called?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set an ASP.NET Label text from code behind on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331968/how-do-i-set-an-asp-net-label-text-from-code-behind-on-page-load)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Label` is on `WebForm1` - i.e somewhere in the .aspx you have a line such as

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Then you should place your code in the `Page_Load` event handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Person t = new Person();
    Label1.Text = t.Password;
}
```

`PersonBuilder` has  o access to the contents of the web form and is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

add this `<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>` in .aspx file and add this in `Person t = new Person();
        Label1.Text = t.Password;` to Page load

web page cycle is starts from Page_Load