# Passing parameters beetween .aspx and .aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using **Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate**. I have put a **raw HTML** web form in my Test.aspx file and want to pass the parameters of form-fields (like : Username, password, mobile no. etc.) from **Test.aspx** to **Test.aspx.cs** file. Although, I have written the code for passing the values in the button click function, I can't get the data. I have written "**string u = Request.QueryString["username"];**" for username field (***without quotes***) and so on and another line to print the value in that form itself, that is "**Response.Write(u);**" (without quotes). Here, I can't see the printed values in my form. How can I solve this issue?

Register.aspx file-

```html
<!-- Start Register Section -->
<div id="login-page">
    <div class="layer-stretch">
        <div class="layer-wrapper">
            <div class="layer-container">
                <form class="form-container" action="Register.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="15276e55e6cdfa6911f440f75f64501dc97cc6f4a19102dddb4c47f0c4dd1523ad639943996afef209d6a358056f3b3389a9bcb175b7413ef3547589673a2b7d">
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="fullname" pattern="[A-Z,a-z, ]*" id="register-first-name" runat="server">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-first-name">الاسم الكامل<em> *</em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال اسم كامل صالح!</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="lastname" pattern="[A-Z,a-z, ]*" id="register-last-name">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-last-name">الكنية <em> *</em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال الاسم الصحيح!</span>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" id="register-email" runat="server">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-email">البريد الإلكتروني <em> *</em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال بريد إلكتروني صحيح!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="mobile" pattern="[0-9]*" id="register-mobile" runat="server">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-mobile">رقم الهاتف المحمول <em> *</em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال رقم الجوال صحيح!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" name="password" id="register-password" runat="server">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-password">كلمه السر <em> *</em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال كلمة المرور صالحة (الحد الأدنى 6 حرف)!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="register-confirm-password" runat="server">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-confirm-password">تأكيد كلمة المرور <em> *</em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال تأكيد كلمة المرور (الحد الأدنى 6 حرف)!</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label form-input-icon form-bot-check">
                        <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="number" name="bot-check" id="register-bot" runat="server">
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="register-bot">ما هو 10 زائد 3 =<em>* </em></label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">الرجاء إدخال القيمة الصحيحة!</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="login-condition">بالنقر على "إنشاء حساب" فإنك توافق على موقعنا<br /><a href="Terms and Conditions.aspx">شروط &#38; الظروف</a></div>-->
                    <div class="form-submit">
                        <!-- <button  class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect button button-primary" name="register" onclick="Submit_Click">إصنع حساب</button>-->
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Submit_Click" Text="Submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect button button-primary" />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Register" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect button button-primary" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-link">
                        <span class="paragraph-small">هل لديك حساب؟</span>
                        <a href="Login.aspx">تسجيل الدخول</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Register Section -->
```

Register.aspx.cs file-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MDC_web {
   public partial class Register: System.Web.UI.Page {
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Register button has been clicked!!");
string fn = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["fullname"]);
Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript'> alert('jhkjhjk');</script>");
Response.Write(fn);
string em = Request.QueryString["email"];
Response.Write(em);
string mob = Request.QueryString["mobile"];
Response.Write(mob);
string p = Request.QueryString["password"];
string cp = Request.QueryString["confirmpassword"];
/*if (p.Equals(cp))
{
   string c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(c);
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Register (R_Name, Email, Mobile, R_Pass) values ('" + fn + "','" + em + "'," + mob + ",'" + p + "')", con);
   int r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   if (r == 1)
   {
       Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript'> alert('Registration is successfull!!');</script>");
   }
 }*/
}

/*protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

     Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript'> alert('jhkjhjk');</script>");
     //Response.Write(fn);
 }*/
 }
}
```

Comment: A lack of code in this question makes it hard to actually help.

Comment: Add some details about the problem you are facing and what you have tried till now.Clear questions with all the necessary points would improves your chances of getting good answers

Comment: You know Request.QueryString reads parameters from the URL? Not from the form?

Answer (score 0):

for use form-fields values in .cs you have to do targetting like this

```
string Username = txtUsername.Value.Trim(); (txtUsername is the name of field in aspx)
string Password = txtPassword.Value.Trim();
string Mobile = txtMobile.Value.Trim();
```

the query string is used for passing value trough aspx pages not for aspx to cs

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms is based on a postback to itself. So he can easily grab info from the query string on the same page. The question is if he should be passing sensitive info that way.

Answer (score -1):

You can access asp id from the .aspx in your .aspx.cs.

just give them a unique `ID` and `runat` like so:

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername"></asp:TextBox>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
var username = txtUsername.Text;
```

this is for receiving the text of the textbox. If you want to set the text then simply change it to `txtusername.Text = "test test"`. You can to this also with asp:labels, asp:button etc.
Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331968/how-do-i-set-an-asp-net-label-text-from-code-behind-on-page-load) for more informations

If you want to do that on a button click just make use of the postback which happens after the click.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSumbit" Text="submit"></asp:Button>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
      var username = txtUsername.Text;
      //do username stuff in here
}
```

if you need a ***Tutorial for a login*** form with websforms check one of these:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184050.aspx
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoPABrUknsE

Comment: @irishchieftain sry copied from one of my old projects, will update the code to c#

Comment: @AniruddhaNath did it help?

Comment: No, I have tried it with C# by using the name of my input field but the name of the input field is not showing in .aspx.cs file.

Comment: No its not the name property, its the ID. and make sure runat="server" is set!

Answer (score -2):

Do not transmit a password, in plain text, via a query string. Set up a https connection for your production site - you can do it free with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). You say you added a "raw HTML form" - add plain HTML elements but do not add an extra form element because ASPNET can only handle a single form with a runat="server" attribute.

Then, to use plain HTML, just add runat="server" so that you can grab the data on the server side:

**Test.aspx:**

```
User Name: <input type="text" name="userName" runat="server">
```

**Test.aspx.cs**

```
string userName = userName.Value.Trim();
```

**UPDATE:**

If you're using a master page, why have you got a form tag in the aspx? The master page usually contains the form tag so it looks like you're copying and pasting code from somewhere else. Remove the form tag from your aspx.

Don't pass sensitive information in the URL via a query string. Use a single form tag in your master page, then in your code-behind:

```
string fName = register-first-name.Value;
```

You're using ASPNET so there is no point in the pattern attribute. Simply add a [Regular Expression validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e(v=vs.71).aspx) control.

Comment: Tried this but the userName is not coming in .aspx.cs

Comment: Show us your markup and code snippets. Make sure you have just a single form and the runat attribute added to any HTML element you need to access in the code-behind.

Comment: Okay. I will give it tomorrow.

Comment: I have disabled the <form> tag of my master page and written the <form> tag here in the Register.aspx page.

Comment: 1st of all, the Register button is not working. I just want to print a message in the output window that my button is working or not. but VS prints nothing. I have inserted a code here: System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Register button has been clicked!!");                  but it's not working.

Comment: string fName = register-first-name.Value;
This code is not working. The register-first-name showing error.

Comment: @AniruddhaNath why do you use .Value and not .Text? and as IrishChieftain said, dont use a seperate form in the Register.aspx. Leave the one in the masterpage

Comment: He uses .Value because it's a HTML control.